# How to quickly go to bottom line of pasted code ipython shell

Tags: python, shell, ipython

I am running python 3.5 in the ipython interactive shell.
I used the %load magic command to continue my session, but the cursor was at the top and I am now having to scroll line by line to the bottom.  Is there some keyboard shortcut in ipython that can get me to the bottom line?

I know there is the %run magic command, but not quite what I'm looking for here as I ran it, and realized I made a mistake, so wanted to run the edited new block of code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want the <kbd>PgDn</kbd> key.